# How can i concatenate a const char with char array?

Tags: c++

The array itself is held at

```
char filestring[9];
```

and initialized via

```
snprintf_P(filestring,
           sizeof(filestring),
           PSTR("%04u%02u%02u"),
           dt.Year(),
           dt.Month(),
           dt.Day());
```

How can i concatenate all above as in the example? (Add the slash and the .txt extension to the filestring variable)

```
File file = SD.open("/" + filestring + ".txt", FILE_APPEND);
```

I get the following misleading error for the example above.

```
expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
```

Comment: You need to build the new string. There is no operator + for character arrays.

Comment: Why not construct `filestring` with the extra text?  Like, `"/%04u%02u%02u.txt"`?  (You'll have to declare the `filestring` array bigger, though.)

Comment: The function `snprintf_P` is not part of ISO C. Therefore, it must either be a platform-specific function or a user-defined function. Please ask the question using ISO C code or mark the question as platform-specific, by adding an appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: `dt.Year()` and `SD.open()` look like C++ to me. Are you sure you are learning the right language? (I know it could be valid C in theory, but in practice this is rather unlikely).

Comment: @SteveSummit That was a brilliant idea. Thanks!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Just added the c++ tag

Comment: Simplify your life, use `std::string`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: I found this description of `snprintf_P`: "It is identical to `snprintf()` except that it reads the format string from the Flash memory, and therefore reduces the RAM consumption".  So this effectively is a question about ISO standard `snprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
char filename[MAX_PATH] = {0};
int n = snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "/%s.txt", filestring);
// check whether snprintf succeeded
if (n > 0 && n < sizeof(filename)) {
    File file = SD.open(filename, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

**Update:** As requested by a user I am adding a clarification on `MAX_PATH`:

The line

```
char filename[MAX_PATH] = {0};
```

Defines a character array of size `MAX_PATH`. That could have used any integer value that you thought right for your program but, using `MAX_PATH` ensures the buffers can hold any filename.

On Linux, you must `#include <limits.h>` (or you can `#include <stdio.h>` and use `FILENAME_MAX`). I am not a Windows user but it looks like you have to `#include <stdlib.h>` to import `MAX_PATH` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/path-field-limits?view=msvc-160)).

Of course you could also also initialized `filestring` with the desired format in one go:

```
char filestring[MAX_PATH];
snprintf_P(filestring,
           sizeof(filestring),
           PSTR("/%04u%02u%02u.txt"),
           dt.Year(),
           dt.Month(),
           dt.Day());
```

Comment: "Maybe" use your commenting privilege to first clarify whatever doubt you have in the reliability and applicability of your solution. Then add some explanation, to avoid the impression that you provide a questionable, unexplained code-only answer which even the author is not sure about.

Comment: JuanR, Since code does not check the return value of `snprintf()`, potentially  incurring problems down the road, could use `sprintf(filename, "/%s.txt", filestring);` and risk UB there.   OR check the return value of `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

In C:

```c
const int size = MAX_PATH;
char path[size];

int rc = snprintf(path, size, "/%s.txt", filestring);
if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Concatenation error.\n");
} else if (rc > size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Buffer is too small.\n");
} else {
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
    // Use it...
}
```

In C++ (since you tagged your question `C++`):

```cpp
std::string path = "/" + std::string(filestring) + ".txt";
File file = SD.open(path.c_str(), FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to build the filename and a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to pass the result around to other functions:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void some_function() {
           
    std::ostringstream os;

    // build the string using the std::ostringstream
    os << std::setfill('0')
       << '/'
       << std::setw(4) << dt.Year()
       << std::setw(2) << dt.Month()
       << std::setw(2) << dt.Day()
       << ".txt";

    // extract the result into a std::string
    std::string filestring(os.str());
    
    // Then depending on the SD.open() interface:

    // 1. The preferred:
    File file = SD.open(filestring, FILE_APPEND);

    // 2. Backup version:
    File file = SD.open(filestring.c_str(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```